# IntelliJ Gradle Location

Tags: intellij-idea, build.gradle

**Background:** I was using Gradle ver 6.5 & now started using ver 7.2

**Issue:** IntelliJ downloads ver 6.5, despite making changes in Settings & Windows Environment variables pointing to ver 7.2

In IntelliJ for the Gradle settings, I have specified the below:

```
Build,Execution,Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle

Use Gradle from: 'wrapper' task in Gradle build script
```

Gradle Script for wrapper:

```
wrapper{
    gradleVersion = '7.2'
    distributionType = Wrapper.DistributionType.BIN
}
```

I notice that version 6.5 is downloaded as well in the project's .gradle folder. But if I specify the Gradle location directly instead of pointing to wrapper, then it does not download version 6.5

I have checked the Gradle build script & do not find any reference to gradle version 6.5, but it still picks it up. May I know from where is ver 6.5 being picked when specifying use wrapper Task in build script.

Hope query is clear await inputs.

Comment: Did you only change the version in the wrapper task configuration or did you also actually run the task? If you run the task, it should update the URL in the file `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`,  which is used to download Gradle.

Comment: @dunni thanks I believe I had missed that step. Kindly upgrade your post as answer, so I can mark it accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you update the version in the `wrapper` task, you have to execute the task once, so that the URL in the file `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` is updated as well. That URL is used by the wrapper script as well as IntelliJ (if configured that way) to download the correct Gradle distribution.